# Как соединить строки, которые находятся в кортежах внутри списка в Python?

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть цикл, который перебирает все слова в строках таблицы и делит их на буквенные биграммы с помощью nltk:

```
for i in range(len(my_data['Bigram'])):
    nltk_syll = nltk.word_tokenize(my_data['Base'][i])
    bigramms = list(nltk.bigrams(nltk_syll))
```

Вывод получается таким:

```
[(о, с), (с, н), (н, о), (о, в), (в, а)]
[(л, у), (у, н), (н, а)]
```

В идеале мне хотелось бы преобразовать это в то, что печатает `print(*map(''.join, bigramms), sep=' ')`, но не печатать, а записать в `my_data['Bigram'][i]`. А именно :

ос сн но ов ва

лу ун на

С помощью `my_data['Bigram'][i] = ''.join(map(str, bigramms))` у меня получается сделать вывод:

```
('о', 'с')('с', 'н')('н', 'о')('о', 'в')('в', 'а')
('л', 'у')('у', 'н')('н', 'а')
```

Как объединить буквы без кавычек, запятых, кортежей и списков?

Comment: Можете предоставить хотя бы упрощённый пример входных данных?

Comment: о с н о в а  например, т.е. в каждой строке слова разбиты на буквы чередующиеся с пробелом

Comment: `my_data['Bigram'][i] = ' '.join(''.join(x) for x in my_data['Bigram'][i])`

Comment: большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
inp = """
о с н о в а
л у н а
я б л о к о
а п е л ь с и н
""".strip()

for line in inp.splitlines():
  # Если это пустая строка - пропускаем её
  if not line:
    continue

  # Убираем пробелы по бокам, которые могли случайно затесаться
  line = line.strip()

  # В качестве начального символа берём нулевой (т.к. точно знаем, что строка не пустая и начинается с символа)
  a = line[0]
  bigramm = []

  # Для всех последующих букв добавляем биграмму с предыдущей, обновляем первую букву
  for letter in line.split()[1:]:
    bigramm += [(a, letter)]
    a = letter

  # Получаем строковый результат из списков биграмм
  result = ' '.join(
    ''.join(elem)
    for elem in bigramm
  )

  # Выводим результат
  print(result)
```

Результат:

```
ос сн но ов ва
лу ун на
яб бл ло ок ко
ап пе ел ль ьс си ин
```

P.s. для проверки правильности разбиения на биграммы, результат вывода самих списков:

```
[('о', 'с'), ('с', 'н'), ('н', 'о'), ('о', 'в'), ('в', 'а')]
[('л', 'у'), ('у', 'н'), ('н', 'а')]
[('я', 'б'), ('б', 'л'), ('л', 'о'), ('о', 'к'), ('к', 'о')]
[('а', 'п'), ('п', 'е'), ('е', 'л'), ('л', 'ь'), ('ь', 'с'), ('с', 'и'), ('и', 'н')]
```

Comment: спасибо, очень полезно и без nltk !

Comment: @Natasha если ответ решает ваш вопрос, вы можете поставить галочку слева от него, чтобы отметить ответ, как правильный

Answer (score 0):

```
a= [ ('о', 'с'),('с', 'н'),('н', 'о'),('о', 'в'),('в', 'а') ]
b=""
for i in range(len(a)):
    b+=a[i][0]    
    b+=a[i][1]    #а это можно убрать и последнюю букву дописать после цикла
#b+=a[len(a)-1][1]
print(b)
```

Comment: спасбо за подсказку!